# How can I make this button get clicked on scroll down for infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here the button loads data from database. Works fine.

```
<li class="getmore" id="'.$post_id.'"><a>Load More  Posts</a></li>
```

How can I make this button to get clicked automatically on scroll down to the bottom of the page . simply the infinite scroll.

should i use window scroll function .If yes then how can do it in this code.

I have tried by pasting the ajax code inside this function but not working.

**Edit :**
1. when I put the Ajax inside scroll function,It shows mysql error in getmore.php.
2. if I put the button class with  click function inside scrolling function then it fires too fast that loads the same posts multiple times.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {

  }
});


$('body').on('click','.getmore',function(){

  var lastelement = $(this ).attr('id');
      
  $.ajax({
    type       : 'GET',
    url        : 'getmore.php',
    data       : 'lastelement='+lastelement,
    beforesend :  function(){

      $('.getmore').html('loading....');

    }, 
    success: function(data){
      $('.getmore').remove();
      $('#recs') .append(data) ; 
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<?php

      $lastelement = $_REQUEST['lastelement' ];
      include("connect2.php");

      if ($lastelement!=''){

        $query   = "SELECT * FROM `posts` "

                 . "WHERE (id < " . $lastelement . " AND "
                 .         "post_keywords like '%home%') " 

                 . "ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC  "
                 . "LIMIT 10";

        $records = mysql_query($query);


        if (mysql_num_rows($records)) {
     
          while($record = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

            $cookie_name = 'tcVotingSystem'.$record['id'];
      $post_title = $record['post_title'];
            $post_id = $record['id'];
            $post_date = $record['post_date'];
            $post_author = $record['post_author'];
            $post_image = $record['post_image'];

            $post_image2 = $record['post_image2'];
            $post_keywords = $record['post_keywords'];
            $post_content = substr($record['post_content'],0,100);
?>

<div>
  //posts goes here
</div>
```

Comment: why you are removing the load button in ajax success by `$('.getmore').remove();`?

Comment: because inside the getmore.php,  the same button  comes again at the bottom.

Comment: And what the problem to put $('.getmore').click(); inside your JS scroll-conditional function?

Comment: @Daniel the problem is that it fires multiple time. each post is coming  2-3 times. when scrolling fast it loads the same post even more than 5 times . 

only way get it perfectly is to scroll super slowly . if multiple fires can be stopped then it will work for me

Comment: Is it reliable to get last post ID, setted on AJAX-success as initial offset for query and make some post counter increase on each beforeSend action for you? It's looks more predictable and simple way to not load duplicates.

Comment: how can i do that ?? any hints

Comment: is it possible to click once then disable the button for a couple of seconds?

Comment: I make some draft about it here because comment is the worst place for code ) http://simp.ly/publish/G0jkgb

Comment: You can make local variable var allowToClick and set it false after first click and true - after timeout. And all AJAX axtion inside if(allowToClick){}

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is fire off the same Ajax request your button down once the scroll reaches a certain point. So instead of inserting the click event function on scroll, rather fire off your Ajax event

Example:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {

    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'getmore.php',
         data:'lastelement='+lastelement,
            beforesend: function(){
                $('.getmore').html('loading....');
            },       
            success: function(data){
                $('.getmore').remove();
                $('#recs') .append(data) ; 
            }
    });
    }
});
```

The above is just an example. As an aside, I would recommend that you create a function for your lazy loading ajax call as you may need to use it more than once i.e On click and scroll.

Hope this helps

Comment: `I have tried by pasting the ajax code inside this function but not working` this is from question. so I guess OP has already tried this approach.

Comment: I have tried this  and  there is  a problem . It fires multiple time .  same post comes 2-3 time . If there are anyway to solve the problem  then i can use this

Comment: Please share your final implementation?

Comment: simply  put  $('.getmore').click();   inside the window scrolling function . it works but  loads same post  multiple times

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple load during fast scroll you can go for this simple approach:

```
var isLoadingNewPage = false; //initializing the flag

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height())
    {
        if(!isLoadingNewPage)
        {
            $('.getmore').click(); //go for next page load
        }
    }


    $('body').on('click','.getmore',function(){
     //if the ajax request is going on then don't make another request; simply return back
     if(isLoadingNewPage)
         return; 

     var lastelement = $(this ).attr('id');

     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getmore.php',
            data:'lastelement='+lastelement,
            beforesend: function(){
                $('.getmore').html('loading....');
                isLoadingNewPage = true; //setting the flag so that no more call needed till the time response comes back
            },       
            success: function(data){
                $('.getmore').remove();
                $('#recs') .append(data) ;

                isLoadingNewPage = false; //resetting the flag so that ajax can happen again if user scroll again
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: same thing is happening ...... should i change the getmore.php . I think problem is with the lastelement . wihtin a sec it can not detect the  new loaded post's id so it loads the same thing multiple times . what should i do here

Comment: is it possible to click once then disable the button for a couple of seconds?

Comment: unable to visualize the issue. could you please try one more time with updated answer. Just modified a bit.

Answer (score 0):

another approach can be this, put a button at the end of page, so while scrolling you can check if the button is entering in viewport and trigger the click

To avoid to show the same posts everytimes change the getmore ID with the last ID retrieved from ajax call

```
        $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
                        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
                        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
                        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
                        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
                    };

                 if ($('.getmore').isInViewport()) {
                    $('.getmore').click();
                 } 

                $(window).scroll(function(){
                   if ($('.getmore').isInViewport()) {
                    $('.getmore').click();
                 } 

            $('body').on('click','.getmore',function(){

              var lastelement = $(this ).attr('id');

              $.ajax({
                type       : 'GET',
                url        : 'getmore.php',
                data       : 'lastelement='+lastelement,
                beforesend :  function(){

                  $('.getmore').html('loading....');

                }, 
                success: function(data){
    /*
to avoid to show the same posts everytimes 
 change the getmore ID with the last ID retrieved from ajax call 
*/
                  $('.getmore').attr('id', (lastelement + $('.getmore').attr('id')));
                  $('#recs') .append(data) ; 
                }
              });

            });
                });
```

when your ajax response will be empty than you can remove the .getmore button

Such as suggested in other answer introduce a isLoadingNewPage variable is a good practice